# Custom CSS overrides not taking effect in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, overriding

I'm using the ReStart Bootstrap template in an ASP.NET MVC application and have applied a bunch of CSS overrides in a child stylesheet. For some reason, not all of the overrides are taking effect in my Chrome browser, though I'm positive the selectors are all named correctly. I've also placed the link to the child stylesheet after the link to the parent sheet in my HTML markup to ensure it loads in the correct order.

Here's an example where-in I am merely changing the background color of a single element:

Parent styling as it appears in `style.css` sheet:

```
#social_media_wrapper {
  background: #428bca;
}
```

Child styling in `site.css` sheet:

```
#social_media_wrapper {
  background: #ff8000;
}
```

Here is the element's HTML reference:

```
            <div id="social_media_wrapper">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square" target="_blank"></i></a>
            </div>
```

Not sure what else would be missing here that would cause these child stylings to be ignored by the browser, as there is nothing in the parent styling marked `!important` that would prevent a child styling from overriding (especially since other child styles that live in the same document are overriding their parents without any issue).

Comment: have you tried debugging by adding `!important` into the child stylesheet? this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tc0q5t7r/2/) proves the browser will give precedence to the second of two selectors loaded sequentially

Comment: Thanks @ToniLeigh for the debug suggestion. Discovered I was missing an ending curly brace for a selector at the top of the document, which Visual Studio didn't catch (but Chrome obviously did).

Comment: nice one, was going to suggest the chrome inspector too, it's excellent !

Comment: for the record, this is one of the rare cases where `!important` is useful, ie. it is very likely to over-ride other selectors and allow you to eliminate failed file loads or selector format errors, it's not completely fool-proof, if your css still doesn't appear then it's possible there's another `!important` over-riding it

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
#social_media_wrapper {
  background-color: #ff8000 !important;
}
```

I hope this might help.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
#social_media_wrapper {
  background: #ff8000;
}
```

to

```
#social_media_wrapper {
  background-color: #ff8000;
}
```

Comment: that shouldn't make a difference, what is the reasoning behind this suggestion?